# How to install sunbird in ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: software-installation

How do I install sunbird in ubuntu 12.10?

I have the `tar.bz2` file but I'm unsure what to do with it. When I extract it and click the executable nothing happens. I have checked the box that says `Allow executing file as a program`.

Comment: Please provide us a link to where you downloaded the tar.bz2. Please see:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sunbird

Comment: Try running the executable from the command line to see if you get an error message. If you do, please include it in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you download from [here](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/calendar/sunbird/download.html)?

Open the terminal and navigate to the download location (may be `cd /home/user/Desktop` or /home/user/Downloads). Then, unpack the compressed file with this command:

```
tar xjvf sunbird*.tar.bz2
```

Then, navigate to the directory that was formed (cd /home/user/Downloads/sunbird/) and start the sunbird script.

```
./sunbird
```

If you want to run it in the background, use the `&` key like this:

```
./sunbird &
```

If you get a permissions error, then run this command before trying again with `./sunbird`

```
chmod u+x sunbird
```

You can also do this with the Archive Manager by extracting the folder and running the same `sunbird` script.

Comment: how do I install it into the launcher?

Comment: not sure, and maybe someone else can help with the unity aspect. you can make a shortcut to the sunbird script and then paste it to the desktop and maybe launcher. You will likely have to change the permissions of the shortcut in order to run.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your 'start menu', right-click and choose edit, go to lets say 'Internet' section, click 'New Item', name the launcher Sunbird and choose a path to folder and sunbird file. I have moved my sunbird folder to .local/share so the paths leads there. Hope this helps.